# Custom category page title in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

On some Woocommerce category pages I would like to change the default Category Page title to something custom. I dont want to change the original "name" on the backend.

Is there some code that I can use for this in functions.php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will allow you to customize the page title on Woocommerce product category pages, for specific product categories:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_page_title', 'customize_woocommerce_page_title', 10, 1 );
function customize_woocommerce_page_title( $page_title) {

    // Custom title for the product category 't-shirts'
    if ( is_product_category('t-shirts') ) {
        $page_title = 'Something';
    }
    // Custom title for the product category 'hoodies'
    elseif ( is_product_category('hoodies') ) {
        $page_title = 'Something else';
    }
    return $page_title;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and work.